# search username ,hashtag on twitter using fabric api

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-fabric

i am trying to serach username ,hastag by using fabric api . but it always give me o count . may i know how to get username and hastag

my code as below

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY,
            TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    SearchTimeline searchTimeline = new SearchTimeline.Builder().query(
            "#twitterflock").build();
    final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(
            this).setTimeline(searchTimeline).build();
    Log.v("ta", "" + adapter.getCount());
```

can any one help me out

Answer (score 0):

this is a working example of searching a username/hashtag (i'm using this on my App):

```
private static final String SEARCH_QUERY = "almounir"; //the username or Hshgtag

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout. activity_main);

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
//lv.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.loading)); d'ont forget to add loading pic 

SearchTimeline searchTimeline = new SearchTimeline.Builder().query(SEARCH_QUERY).build();

final TweetTimelineListAdapter timelineAdapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter(this, searchTimeline);

lv.setAdapter(timelineAdapter);
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Get user name from active session and set it for getting timeline.

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
     String userName = session.getUserName();

    final SearchTimeline searchTimeline = new SearchTimeline.Builder()
            .query(userName)
            .build();
    final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTimeline(searchTimeline)
                    .build();
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
```